# Why does this Rails ajax partial refresh on first request, but not on subsequent requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a frustrating issue with an ajaxified Rails partial. On the first request, the partial is replaced as expected. On all subsequent requests, the partial appears to be load correctly, but it is not added to the DOM. I must be overlooking something obvious here (perhaps Turbolinks related?). Can anyone help?

```
#myobjects/index.html.erb

<div id="container">
<%= render partial: "myobjects/myobject", collection: @myobjects %>
</div>

<%= link_to "All", myobjects_path, remote: true %>
<%= link_to "Approved", myobjects_path(filtered: "approved"), remote: true %>
<%= link_to "Rejected", myobjects_path(filtered: "rejected"), remote: true %>

#myobjects/index.js.erb
$('#container').html("<%= render partial: 'myobjects/myobject', collection: @myobjects");
```

Example:

1. I load the `myobjects` index, all records are displayed.
2. I click the `Approved` link, only approved records are displayed.
3. I click one of the other links, the DOM does not change.

I can see that the `myobjects/_myobject.html.erb` partial is being loaded correctly, even at point 3 above. If I add `<% Rail.logger.info myobject.to_yaml %>` the correct records details are being printed to the log. Yet the partial is not added to the DOM.

What am I missing?

Comment: In `link_to "Rejected", myobjects_path(filtered: "approved")`, shouldn't that last string be `"rejected"`?

Comment: thanks @Phlip, yes you are correct. A typo! This issue is not in the code.

Comment: After the first click loads the partial by Ajax, does the `<div id="container">` still exist? or does the `.html()` JavaScript call blot it out? Use your web browser's Inspect to go looking for it.

Comment: Nevermind. I had overlooked an obvious issue! My ajax partial did not have `*javascript* render partial`. You would not believe how much time I have wasted trying to figure that out! :)